# Use webview as a widget in kivy

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

[This](http://pasted.co/602fb057) is the code I got from internet which allow to use webview in kivy and it works perfectly well.

However I am unable to use it as a widget. I want to design a carousel with two screens, one with the webview and the other with one of my own widgets.
I wrote the below code but it just renders the webview and I am unable to slide between the two screens.
My [main.py](http://pasted.co/07eb75f6) and pasted . co / ff17b063.
Thanks. (Second link is for rent.kv file. Sorry, I cant post more than 2 links.)

Comment: You'd have do add extra code to move the webview position and/or hide it when necessary. It might be possible to bind this functionality to a kivy widget, but I don't know how and it might be hard to handle some kinds of behaviour.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code? And how to implement it inside a carousel? Thanks.

Comment: No, I've never tried this.